# c++ Binary tree conflicting types error

Tags: c, types, binary-tree, conflict

Q:Could someone give a hint, why inside my program here are conflicting types, even if its the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call a function before it is defined (i.e. earlier in the file than the definition), the compiler won't know the argument types and return type.  You need to have a function prototype before the function is called.  Usually people put function prototypes in header files, but you could just add one near the top of your file.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand that order in this case matters and if I put prototype inside the header, then I could put my functions before or after calling function.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a '}' before the definition of a balance_tree. like that:

```
    exit(-1)
}
}      /* this one */

treeNode* balance_tree(treeNode* currentNode) {
```